# Fatal error: Call to a member function return_module_option() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ges\ges-admin\application_list.php on line 107

Tags: php

This is my code

```
require "../ges-admin/class/modules.php";
$module = new modules();    
echo $module->return_module_option("");
Page:application_list.php
```

This is my class code:

```
class modules {
        private function get_module($selid){
            $getconn = new dbconnect();
            $conn    = $getconn->getconn();
            $sel_module = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `ielts_module` WHERE `status`='1'");
            while($fetch_module = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_module))
            {
                ?>
                <option <?php if($selid==$fetch_module['id']){ echo "selected=selected"; }?> value="<?php echo $fetch_module['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_module['modules']; ?></option>
                <?php   
            }
        }

        private function module_name($mid){
            $getconn = new dbconnect();
            $conn    = $getconn->getconn();
            $sel_module = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `modules` FROM `ielts_module` WHERE `id`='$mid'"); 
            $fetch_module = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_module);
            return $fetch_module['modules'];
        }

        public function return_module_option($selid){
            return $this->get_module($selid);
        }

        public function get_module_name($mid)
        {
            return $this->module_name($mid);        
        }
    }
```

This `echo $module->return_module_option("");` code is works fine when page loads after submitting the form through get method, it shows

Fatal error:  Call to a member function return_module_option() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ges\ges-admin\application_list.php on line 107

Comment: Could you please post line 100-110 of C:\xampp\htdocs\ges\ges-admin\application_list.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm what `new modules()` is returning.  Try outputting `$module` across both the GET and POST requests for the route.  Then correct the reason why `new modules()` isn't returning the correct return type.

`var_dump($modules);`

Also, if you can share your modules class that'd be a start, or at least the constructor.